# What's that movie with a surreal golden tree appearing from time to time?

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama

I once watched a movie of which I only remember a few things... The most present memory is this huge **golden tree**... Or at least I think the tree itself was golden. Then scene in which this tree appeared was golden, too. The sky was golden, the lights, there were **golden particles** and I think there was **a man crawling around the tree**...

This scene appeared several times in the movie, maybe 4 or 5 times... Unfortunately I don't remember the plot... Another thing I remember that it was a rather **sad, dramatic movie**. I also remember a **woman lying in a bed**, maybe she was deathly ill, I'm not sure about this. There might be the possibility that this woman and her illness was very important, there were often people visiting her.

I'm not sure about the ill woman, but I definitely remember this **bizarre, surreal scene of a tree surrounded by gold**.

I hope someone knows which movie that was, because I'd like to watch it again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not actually seen the film but reading this could it be, [**The Fountain**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0414993/)

Had Hugh Jackman as the lead and it just sprung to mind from the trailer.

Comment: Just reading the first sentence from the question, that's also the first movie that came to mind. It likely the most bizarre movie I ever saw.